# XLST Query using XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<countries>
  <country name="Afghanistan" population="22664136" area="647500">
    <language percentage="11">Turkic</language>
    <language percentage="35">Pashtu</language>
    <language percentage="50">Afghan Persian</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Albania" population="3249136" area="28750"/>
  <country name="Algeria" population="29183032" area="2381740">
    <city>
      <name>Algiers</name>
      <population>1507241</population>
    </city>
  </country>
  <country name="American Samoa" population="59566" area="199"/>
  <country name="Andorra" population="72766" area="450"/>
  <country name="Angola" population="10342899" area="1246700"/>
  <country name="Anguilla" population="10424" area="91">
    <language percentage="100">English</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Antigua and Barbuda" population="65647" area="440">
    <language percentage="100">English</language>
  </country>
 .....
```

Hello first of all with this XSLT I would like to get the names of the countries whose language ends in 'ian' (like Russian ...), so i have this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <countries>
            <xsl:for-each select="countries/country[substring('language', 3) = 'ian']">
                <country>
                    <nom><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></nom>
                    <idiomes>
                        <xsl:value-of select="language"/>
                    </idiomes>
                </country>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </countries>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone help me please..

Comment: And i don't get any thing.. Some idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath to get `coutry` nodes with `language` ends-with `"ian"`:

```
countries/country[language[substring(., string-length(.) - 2)="ian"]]
```

Some clarifications:

`language[substring(., string-length(.) - 2)="ian"]` predicate means *`language` which text content last 3 chars are equal to `"ian"`*.

`string-length(.) - 2` means *start counting characters from the language length - 2*.

For example, if `language` content is `"Pashtu"` (6 chars length), then `string-length(.) - 2` is `6 - 2 = 4` and so we should start from index `4` which is `"h"` (Note that in XPath first index is `1`, but not `0`). Starting from index `4` our substring will be `"htu"`. `"htu" != "ian"`

Comment: Thank you so much, i started working with XSLT 2 days ago, i'm so noob yet xD

Answer (score 1):

If you really use `version="2.0"` of XSLT then using `language[ends-with(., 'ian')]` seems the easiest approach to check there is a language element ending in `ian`.